# Weighted Likelihood of an Event Occurring

Tags: r, statistics, prediction

I want to identify the probability of certain events occurring for a range.

Min = 600 Max = 50,000 Most frequent outcome = 600

I generated a sequence of events: `numbers <- seq(600,50000,by=1)`

This is where I get stuck. Not sure if using the wrong distribution or attempt at execution is going down the wrong path.

`qpois(numbers, lambda = 600)` produces NaNs

So the outcome desired is to be able to get an output of weighted probabilities (weighted to the mean of 600). And then be able to assess the likelihood of an outlier event about 30000 is 5% or different cuts like that by summing the probabilities for those numbers.

A bit rusty, haven't used this for a few years so any online resources to refresh is also appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you're looking for `ppois` rather than `qpois`. The function `qpois(p, 600)` takes a vector `p` of *probabilities*. If you do `qpois(0.75, 600)` you will get 616, meaning that 75% of observations will be at or below 616.

`ppois` is the opposite of `qpois`. If you do `ppois(616, 600)` you will get (approximately) 0.75.

As for your specific distribution, it can't be a Poisson distribution. Let's see what a Poisson distribution with a mean of 600 looks like:

```
x <- 500:700
plot(x, dpois(x, 600), type = "h")
```

[image]

Getting a value of greater than even 900 has (essentially) a zero probability:

```r
1 - ppois(900, 600)
#> [1] 0
```

So if your data contains values of 30,000 or 50,000 as well as 600, it's certainly not a Poisson distribution.

Without knowing more about your actual data, it's not really possible to say what distribution you have. Perhaps if you include a sample of it in your question we could be of more help.

---

**EDIT**

With the sample of numbers provided in the comments, we can have a look at the actual empirical distribution:

```r
hist(numbers, 200)
```

[image]

and if we want to know the probability at any point, we can create the empirical cumulative distribution function like this:

```r
get_probability_of <- ecdf(numbers)
```

This allows us to do:

```r
number <- 1:50000
plot(number, get_probability_of(number), ylab = "probability", type = "l")
```

[image]

and

```r
get_probability_of(30000)
#> [1] 0.83588
```

Which means that the probability of getting a number higher than 30,000 is

```r
1 - get_probability_of(30000)
#> [1] 0.16412
```

However, in this case, we know how the distribution is generated, so we can calculate the *exact* theoretical cdf just using some simple geometry (I won't show my working here because although it is simple, it is rather lengthy, dull, and not applicable to other distributions):

```r
cdf <- function(x) ifelse(x < 600, 0, 1 - ((49400 - (x - 600)) / 49400)^2)
```

[image]

and

```r
cdf(30000)
#> [1] 0.8360898
```

which is very close to, but more theoretically accurate than the empirical value.

Comment: Sure, here is the randomly generated list [link] (https://filebin.net/sfima1vqlh8vlhas)

Created in python via:
```import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 600
b = 50000
c = 600

num = np.ma.round(np.random.triangular(
          left = a - 0.5,
          mode = c,
          right = b + 0.5, 
          size = 50000)
        )```